# Returning results from facet fields

Tags: search

Is it possible to turn on facet field and use its results in custom module, for custom dropdown list (instead of a block) ? I installed Search API and Facet modules and successfully created facet block, but don't want to see results in a block.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom widget for facet api, after that you can put results from widget into drupal_static as source data.

It's easiest way if not hack facetapi module.

UPD.

Seems I found better solution:

```
$adapter = facetapi_adapter_load('search_api@INDEX NAME'); 
$adapter->processFacets();
$processor = $adapter->getProcessor('FACET NAME');
$facet_values = $processor->getBuild();
```